# How EXPECT_THAT works internally?

Tags: c++, lambda, googletest

My program(C++) is using the `googletest` for testing. I am looking at googletest new feature of `ThrowsMessage` introduced in the v1.11.0.

One of the test function used for testing ThrowsMessage by the googletest program is:

```
TEST(ThrowsTest, Examples)
{
    EXPECT_THAT(std::function<void()>([]() { throw std::runtime_error("message"); }),
                ThrowsMessage<std::runtime_error>(HasSubstr("message")));
}
```

I have a pretty simple question, how is the `lambda` function inside the `EXPECT_THAT` is getting called, that is this piece of code:

```
std::function<void()>([]() { throw std::runtime_error("message"); })
```

Is it something like googletest notice the lambda function, so call it themselves, or am I missing something here?

I am a beginner so it may be a silly question, but afaik the lambda function needs the `()` call to run.

Comment: You can look at the definition of `EXPECT_THAT` and see what it expands to. (It doesn't need to "notice" anything, it requires something callable.)

Answer (score 1):

`EXPECT_THAT` ensures that matcher, which was returned from `ThrowsMessage`, can match value `std::function<void()>`. From comment above matcher's implementation:

```
// This matcher accepts a callable and verifies that when invoked, it throws
// an exception with the given type and properties.
```

And in implementation [itself](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/53495a2a7d6ba7e0691a7f3602e9a5324bba6e45/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h#L5143):

```
(void)(std::forward<T>(x)());
```

To catch exception for callable you need to wrap it's call with `try-catch` block so it will be not possible to catch anything if instead of callable we will use returned value.